# TypeError: Cannot read property 'findById' of null

Tags: node.js, express, mongodb-query

Everything works fine except when I submit the edit page.It seems it can not find the ID.
 Please Help look at the code below and see whats wrong: the error message is attached in the picture embeded in the link below:I have all the pages set up correctly:

Error Message is in the image below: 
[image: Photo]

---

Code:

```js
//POST Edit page

router.post('/edit-page/:slug', function(req, res) {
  req.checkBody('title', 'Title must have a vlaue.').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('content', 'Content must have a value.').notEmpty();

  var title = req.body.title;
  var slug = req.body.slug.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
  if (slug == "") slug = title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

  var content = req.body.content;
  var id = req.body.id;
  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    res.render('admin/edit_page', {
      errors: errors,
      title: title,
      slug: slug,
      content: content,
      id: id

    });
  } else {
    Page.findOne({
      slug: slug,
      _id: {
        '$ne': id
      }
    }, function(err, page) {
      if (page) {
        req.flash('danger', 'Page slug exists, choose another.');
        res.render('admin/edit_page', {
          title: title,
          slug: slug,
          content: content,
          id: id

        });

      } else {
        console.log("I am this far...")
        page.findById(id, function(err, page) {

          if (err)
            console.log("How about here?");
          return console.log(err);
          page.title = title;
          page.slug = slug;
          page.content = content;

          page.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
              return console.log(err);
            req.flash('success', 'Page added!');
            res.redirect('/admin/pages/edit-page/' + page.slug);

          });
        });


      }

    });

  }


});
```

Comment: You are putting a condition to check if _page_ is not falsy. In the other hand of the condition you try to access to _page_ that you are already know it is falsy (securely _null_ because of the callback of _Page.findOne_, so... the error is expected.

Comment: @dez Oh...I see... I was actually following a tutorial and his code works while mine didn't work...Can you suggest a way out?

Answer (score 1):

- It's a typo. **Use `Page.findById` instead of `page.findById`**
- Also `page` is `undefined` because it's in the `else` of the `if(page)` statement

Comment: @molamk...Thank you for the feedback> I have tried it but the error i got is below:Server started on port 3000
Connected to mongo dbI am this far...
null